# Problem of modules over PID, Exercise $9.13(2)$ in Rotman's Advanced Modern Algebra $2$nd Edition

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

Rotman's *Advanced Modern Algebra* ($3$rd Edition), Exercise B-$3.24(2)$, also Exercise $9.13(2)$ in $2$nd Edition.

> $R$ is PID, $M$ is $P$-primary $R$-module. $P=(p)$ is non-zero prime ideal. $k_P:=R/P$ is field.
>
> Define $M[p]:=\{m\in M, pm=0 \}$ and $V_P(n,M):=\text{dim}_{k_P}\frac{p^nM\ \cap M[p]}{p^{n+1}M\ \cap M[p]}.$
>
> Suppose $M$ is direct sum of cyclic modules $C_i$, prove the number of summands $C_i$ having order ideal/annihilator $\color{blue}{(p^{n+1})}$ is $V_P(n,M)$.

**Attention**: The book ($3$rd Edition) originally writes "$\ldots$$C_i$ having order ideal/annihilator $(p^{n})$ is $V_P(n,M)$", but that's **wrong** and should be $\color{red}{(p^{n+1})}$ instead.

I wrote my thoughts in my answer below.

Comment: What is (1) that you're referencing?

Comment: Ok, found a copy of the textbook, but I'm not sure where the notation $U_P(n,M)$ is from. That said, I think I have a better idea of what you're asking.

Comment: @jgon Sorry for not showing what $U_P(n,M)$ means. I found some of my thoughts are entirely wrong and some topos, now they're deleted or corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things. I found the second edition online, so I'm working from that.

I found your question a little unclear, so the first part of this is me working through it trying to figure out precisely what you're asking and why. **Edit** It has since been clarified, and the contradiction resolved.

Regardless of your work, there is an obvious contradiction in the statements.
We have

1. $U_P(n,M)=\#\{\text{cyclic summands w/ order $p^{n+1}$}\}$ (Theorem 9.14)
2. $U_P(n,M)=V_P(n,M)$ for $M$ f.g. (Ex 9.13 (i))
3. $V_P(n,M)=\#\{\text{cyclic summands w/ order $p^{n}$}\}$ (Ex 9.14 (ii))

Now for a finitely generated module $M$, this presents a clear contradiction. This is I presume why you asked the question, you find yourself in the situation of having apparently proved a contradiction, so you need to resolve this situation.

Now as with most textbooks, minor typos are not uncommon. It's not likely for statement 2 to contain a typo, so let's see if we can find an example showing statements 1 or 3 to be false.

**Definitions**

We recall the definitions:

1. $U_P(n,M)=d(p^nM)-d(p^{n+1}M)$, where $d(M)=\dim(M/pM)$ (definition immediately after corollary 9.13)
2. $$V_P(n,M)=\dim \frac{p^nM\cap M[p]}{p^{n+1}M\cap M[p]}$$

Consider $M=R/P$. Then $d(p^nM)=\delta_{0n}$, so $U_P(n,M)=d(p^nM)-d(p^{n+1}M)=\delta_{0n}-\delta_{0,n+1}=\delta_{0n}$. Thus statement 1 holds.

On the other hand, $M[p]=M$, so $V_P(n,M)=\dim(p^nM/p^{n+1}M)=d(p^nM)=d(p^nM)-d(p^{n+1}M)=\delta_{0n}$, since $d(p^{n+1}M)=0$ for all $n\ge 0$. Thus statement 3 is violated.

**How I would prove the corrected version of (3)**

Note that everything is linear across direct sums, so it suffices to prove the statement for a cyclic module.

Consider $M=R/P^{e+1}$. We want to show that $V_P(n,M)=\delta{ne}$.

Now $M[p]=P^e/P^{e+1}$, and $p^nM = P^n/P^{e+1}$ when $n \le e$ and $0$ otherwise.
Then $p^nM\cap M[p]= P^e/P^{e+1}$ for $n\le e$, and $0$ otherwise.
Hence if $n < e$, $$p^nM\cap M[p] = P^e/P^{e+1} = p^{n+1}M\cap M[p],$$
if $n > e$, then 
$$p^nM\cap M[p] = 0 = p^{n+1}M\cap M[p],$$
and if $n=e$, then
$$p^nM\cap M[p] = P^e/P^{e+1},\text{ but } p^{n+1}M\cap M[p]=0,$$ 
so $V_P(e,M)=1\dim P^e/P^{e+1}=1$.

Thus $V_P(n,M)=\delta_{ne}$ as desired.

Comment: Thanks for your kindly explaination. As I mentioned, it should be $(p^{n+1})$ instead of $(p^n)$ in the book. I deleted it because I worked it out.

Comment: @Andrews, yes I realized that, but I'd already written almost the entire answer by that point, so I edited in a comment and left the rest of my answer as is

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $M=M_P \cong \bigoplus_{e_m\geq1} R/P^{e_m},$ then $M[p]\cong \bigoplus_{e_n\geq0}P^{e_n}/P^{e_n+1}.$

$p^nM = \bigoplus_{e_m\geq1} P^n/P^{e_m}\cong \bigoplus_{e_m\geq n+1} P^n/P^{e_m}$.

$p^nM \cap M[p]\cong \bigoplus_{e_m\geq n+1}P^{e_m-1}/P^{e_m}$.

$p^{n+1}M = \bigoplus_{e_m\geq1} P^{n+1}/P^{e_m}\cong \bigoplus_{e_m\geq n+2} P^n/P^{e_m}$.

$p^{n+1}M \cap M[p]\cong \bigoplus_{e_m\geq n+2}P^{e_m-1}/P^{e_m}$.

Thus $(p^nM \cap M[p])/(p^{n+1}M \cap M[p])\cong\bigoplus_{e_m=n+1}P^{e_m-1}/P^{e_m}\cong(R/P)^{\oplus \#\{e_m|e_m=n+1\}}$.

dim$(p^nM \cap M[p])/(p^{n+1}M \cap M[p]) = V_P(n,M)=\#\{e_m|e_m=n+1\}$.

Thus there're $ V_P(n,M)$ $R/P^{n+1}$ as direct summands in $M_P$.